# Find/Replace htmlentities using the standard linux toolchain?

Tags: linux, html-entities, linux-toolchain

Is there a way I can do something like the following using the standard linux toolchain?

Let's say the source at example.com/index.php is:

```
Hello, &amp; world! &quot;
```

How can I do something like this...

```
curl -s http://example.com/index.php | htmlentities
```

...that would print the following:

```
Hello, & world! "
```

Using only the standard linux toolchain?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`recode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/recode.html).

```
$ echo 'Hello, &amp; world! &quot;' | recode HTML_4.0
Hello, & world! "
```

**EDIT**: By the way, `recode` offers several different conversions corresponding to different versions of HTML and XML, so you can use e.g. `HTML_3.2` instead of `HTML_4.0` if you have a really old HTML document. Running `recode -l` will list all the complete list of charsets supported by the program.

Comment: `$ man recode` No manual entry for recode `$ type recode` bash: type: recode: not found (not to say it isn't excellent, but is it part of the standard toolchain?)

Comment: @Stephen: You have to install it first.

Comment: @Stephen P: Evidently it's not installed on your computer. It's debatable (AFAIK) whether or not `recode` is part of the standard toolchain, but it's very common, and if it isn't considered part of the toolchain, I doubt that anything that is could do the job.

Comment: This indeed doesn't seem to be part of the standard toolchain as I requested, but it's in the spirit of such a tool (ie exactly how I wanted) so I've marked it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5):

```
alias decode="php -r 'echo html_entity_decode(fgets( STDIN ));'"

$ echo 'Hello, &amp; world! &quot;' | decode
Hello, & world! "
```

Comment: This is cool, so +1. It doesn't really answer my question though - I was looking for something along the lines of what David provided.

Comment: thanks also, I ended up using both answers as php is included on Macs, otherwise it's recode.